# How to find products with similar components?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to find items that have at least 75%+ similar components in them, we have thousands of products. My table has 2 columns, Item and Component. Example:

```
+------+-----------+
| Item | Component |
+------+-----------+
| AAA  | screw     |
| AAA  | metal     |
| AAA  | bar       |
| AAA  | nut       |
| ABC  | screw     |
| ABC  | metal     |
| ABC  | bar       |
| CAA  | nut       |
| CAA  | cap       |
+------+-----------+
```

The end result I would like to get 3 columns. Item, Item2 and Percentage Similar. So It Would look like:

```
+------+-------+-------------------+
| Item | Item2 | PercentageSimilar |
+------+-------+-------------------+
| AAA  | ABC   | 75%               |
| AAA  | CAA   | 25%               |
| ABC  | AAA   | 100%              |
| ABC  | CAA   | 0%                |
| CAA  | AAA   | 50%               |
| CAA  | ABC   | 0%                |
+------+-------+-------------------+
```

Is this possible to do with SQL?

Comment: How is "ABC" 75% similar to "AAA", "CAA is only 25%" similar to "AAA" - and (my favorite) "ABC" is 0%" similar with "CAA"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your expected results make no sense at all... can you clarify?

Comment: @StanShaw, got me as well I think the similiarties are supposed to come from screw vs nut etc.

Comment: @user6144226 Perhaps, but if that was the case, "AAA" and "ABC" would be 100% similar since the component columns are identical.

Comment: Are you looking like fuzzy lookup, then use Fuzzy lookup in SSIS to get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - a little more info than you asked for, but here is the breakdown so you can understand how to achieve this result:

Setup with sample data:

```
DECLARE @ItemsAndComponents TABLE 
    (
        Item VARCHAR(3), 
        Component VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT INTO @ItemsAndComponents
VALUES
('AAA', 'screw'),
('AAA', 'metal'),
('AAA', 'bar'),
('AAA', 'nut'),
('ABC', 'screw'),
('ABC', 'metal'),
('ABC', 'bar'),
('CAA', 'nut'),
('CAA', 'cap')
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT     
       T1.Item AS [First Item], 
       T2.Item AS [Second Item],
       SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Component = T2.Component THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Matches], 
       COUNT(distinct T1.Component) AS [Total],
       CAST(100. * SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Component = T2.Component THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(distinct T1.Component) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Percent Similar]
FROM @ItemsAndComponents T1
JOIN @ItemsAndComponents T2
    ON T1.Item <> T2.Item
GROUP BY T1.Item, T2.Item
ORDER BY T1.Item, T2.Item
```

Results:

```
First Item Second Item Matches     Total       Percent Similar
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
AAA        ABC         3           4           75.00
AAA        CAA         1           4           25.00
ABC        AAA         3           3           100.00
ABC        CAA         0           3           0.00
CAA        AAA         1           2           50.00
CAA        ABC         0           2           0.00

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This does make it a little easier to understand, thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `self join` to do this.

```
select t1.item,t2.item
,100.*count(case when t1.component=t2.component then 1 end)
 /count(distinct t1.component) as pct_similar
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.item<>t2.item
group by t1.item,t2.item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--creating table
with myTable as (
select 'AAA' as Item , 'screw' as Component union 
select 'AAA' as Item , 'metal' as Component union 
select 'AAA' as Item , 'bar' as Component union 
select 'AAA' as Item , 'nut' as Component union 
select 'ABC' as Item , 'screw' as Component union 
select 'ABC' as Item , 'metal' as Component union 
select 'ABC' as Item , 'bar' as Component union 
select 'CAA' as Item , 'nut' as Component union 
select 'CAA' as Item , 'cap' as Component 
)

--Query
select distinct a.item , b.Item as Item2 ,  
cast((select count(*) from myTable as x inner join myTable as y on x.Item = a.Item and y.Item = b.Item and x.Component = y.Component) *100 /
(select count(*) from myTable where Item = a.item) as nvarchar(3)) +'%'  as Percentage
from myTable as a inner join 
myTable as b on a.Item <> b.item
```

and here is the result:

```
item Item2 Percentage
---- ----- ----------
AAA  ABC   75%
AAA  CAA   25%
ABC  AAA   100%
ABC  CAA   0%
CAA  AAA   50%
CAA  ABC   0%
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you so much for the help